# Is there an app that replaces the phased-out TouchBar?

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, touch-bar, text-input

I have just purchased a new M3 MacBook Pro, and am upgrading from a 2016 15" MacBook Pro (with TouchBar). While this is not a post about whether TouchBar was good or bad, there are a few things about it that I am going to miss.
The most relevant one is the typing prediction strip that helped me countless times with correcting grammar in languages I am not native to.
Besides using the iPad with Sidecar all the time, is there an app that can replace this in the new MacBooks? Something that possibly appears every time one is typing as a moveable floating bar somewhere on the screen.
Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Sonoma has the same "predictive" text as on iOS. It will offer word completion and check grammar.

Comment: But it won’t show it as a floating bar, right? I still have to try it, configuring the new boy in the pauses!

Comment: The suggestions float above the line of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of two such utilities:

[Touché](https://redsweater.com/touche/)

[Touch Bar Simulator](https://github.com/sindresorhus/touch-bar-simulator)

Hopefully one (or both) meet your needs.

Comment: Touché seems the perfect solution! Thank you very much!